# In App Billing: Verify "Already Owned" Result

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I want that my app can restore in app purchases that were made before or with another device (but the same account). So, if getPurchases() is not up-to-date, then at latest when the user tries to buy again, the item should automatically be available again in the app.

There are two cases where `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` can be returned:

1. Directly from getBuyIntent(). This happens when the local Play Store (cached) already knows that the item is already purchased. In this case getPurchases() also reports the item to have been purchased.
2. In handleActivityResult(). This happens when the purchase was made with a second device and the first device still does not know. In this case, the Google Play server is contacted and the server reports that the item has been already purchased.

The problem with (2.) is that no purchseData and no dataSignature is returned so the info cannot be validated.

I have two possibilities:

- accept that I cannot validate the info that the item is owned.
- Tell the user that he/she has to restart the device so the local Play Store refreshes the cached data.

I am not happy with either possibility. Is there a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to request all products with their states anew and validate them. This is what I do in my app after receiving `ALREADY_OWNED` response.

As an idea, you can even accept `ALREADY_OWNED` response as it is (without validation) and enable extended functions to the user. If that was a fraud response, you will still be able to validate it again on a new application launch. If you detect that the item is not owned, you will disable extended functions back.

Comment: But the getPurchases() method does not give updated information. The product which is already owned is still not there in the list from getPurchases(). Testet with Android 2.2 and 4.4 with Play Store 4.6.17

Comment: That's weird. I'm quite sure they were in place when I tested it. But anyway you can enable extended features when you get ALREADY_OVWED. This is safe because you will verify this purchase on every start later on.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. You would expect that the cached purchases are updated after an "ALREADY_OWNED" event. And I have read it somewhere before. But when I am testing, it behaves as I described. But your idea to enable the feature anyway (because it will be tested later again) sounds reasonable. If you add this to your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I updated the answer and I double-checked my code. I always verify signature and payload and it works well. Maybe you check with a test account, and it behaves a bit differently. Not sure. Mentioned workaround should work though.

Comment: I accepted the answer. But there is a problem nevertheless: Even a restart of the app does not update the cached information. The only way is to reboot the whole device (and so restarting the Google Services)